# How to compile Fortran code of unknown dialect and with unknown libraries

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to compile some Fortran code that, according to the documentation, is known to compile with "Intel Fortran Compiler 11." However, when I try to compile the code using the version of ifort that comes with Intel® Fortran Composer XE 2013 for OS X (here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compilers), I get a number of errors. I suspect that I'm either 1) using a compiler that's incompatible with the exact dialect of Fortran used and/or 2) failing to include some necessary libraries.

I'm not a Fortran programmer, so I'm hoping that someone with more experience will be able to glance at the code and recognize if it's just a simple matter of using a different compiler, setting some compiler options, including some specific libraries, or if I'm missing something else altogether.

The full source code can be found just above the Contents here: http://baydeltaoffice.water.ca.gov/modeling/deltamodeling/models/dsm2/dsm2.cfm

To start with, I'm just trying to compile groups.f in /DSM2_v8_0_6_src/dsm2_v8_0/src/common (which requires that a few other modules be compiled first), but the eventual goal is to compile DSM2_v8_0_6_src/dsm2_v8_0/src/ptm/native/fixedData.f and all of its dependencies.

The syntax I'm using follows this basic pattern:

```
ifort -c DSM2_v8_0_6_src/dsm2_v8_0/src/common/groups.f
```

To get a sense of the types of errors I'm encountering, here are a couple of types that occur repeatedly:

```
groups.f(225): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: 
( * ) :: , . % + - [ : . ** / // .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == ...
write(unit_error,*)"Error in matching text pattern:",trim(pattern)
---------------------------------------------------------------------^

groups.f(265): error #5120: Unterminated character constant
&     "Error in pattern matching. Implementation count does not equal count in NumberMatches"
------^
```

Comment: Both of these errors look like they're end-of-line issues. Check that your files use the EOL convention the compiler expects (most likely DOS but you never know...)

Comment: Have you asked the provider of the code for help?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the EOL convention. I may end up having to ask the provider for help, though I'd like to figure it out myself if possible in order to come to the answer more quickly and understand the code more thoroughly.

Comment: took the time to download the code.. looks like fixed format fortran, except lots of lines have a single TAB instead of 6 spaces.  I dont know the best fix, if you filter it replacing tabs with spaces you may make a few lines too long.  (It is a lot of code, hundreds of files..)

Comment: Thanks george. I realize that my question was a bit esoteric, so I appreciate that you took the time to download the code and take a look. Your comment put me on the right track to eventually solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be F77 or F90 depending on how you have done the formatting.  Stack oveflow fomatting requires 4 spaces to start the code.  On the line 225, is it indented by 6 or not indented at all.  If it is indented by 6 and line 265 is indented by 5 then it is F77.

The other question is whether leading spaces have been stripped when moving from one machine to another.  If that is the case then they need to be re-inserted.

On the first line with an error, check the line terminations.  All lines should end with either CR LF or just LF.  If there is a mix, the compiler will throw a wobbly.

If it is F77, try renaming the files with a .f extension to a .for extension.  ifort will then definitely pick them up as f77.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these suggestions a shot.

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help point somebody with a similar problem in the right direction, after doing some digging I was able to determine that the code was originally compiled using Visual Studio with the compiler option FixedFormLineLength="fixedLength132". So, using ifort from the command line, I can compile using the following basic pattern (omitting all of the include paths, etc., for clarity):

```
ifort -c -132 DSM2_v8_0_6_src/dsm2_v8_0/src/common/groups.f
```

As for the dialect, I later heard from the provider that the code was mostly written in Fortran 77, with some parts later revised to Fortran 90.